# Htaccess to change Root image path?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to use .Htaccess to redirect this kind of image path: www.domain.com/dir1/img1.jpg to www.domain.com/wp-content/gallery/dir1/img1.jpg (dir1 is not fixed). Thanks a lot for your help, I'm very bad at regex.

Best,

Marc

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule as your very first rule

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/[\w-]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|tiff|png))$ /wp-content/gallery/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly. However, I was wrong when I asked the question. Actually I'm not looking for a redirect, I would like to keep the original URL www.domain.com/dir1/img1.jpg that would be like an alias, not a redirect. I'm trying to hide the wp-content/... part. Thx

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Now if i use the "www.domain.com/dir1/img1.jpg" link inside an IMG src, it works perfectly. If I use the direct link in a browser, it is rewritten into www.domain.com/wp-content/gallery/dir1/img1.jpg.

Comment: That must be due to your browser cache. Clear your browser cache completely.